# In Jest, is it correct to use setTimeout to wait for DOM manipulation to happen?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I have a function which registers a `click` handler on a button. Once the button is clicked, the variable `NAME` is set to an input element's value.

When I try to click the button and read the `NAME` variable the `expect()` call returns the sam `NAME` value before the `click` event was dispatched.

This is my code (that doesn't work):

```js
test("Input name and receive correctly", () => {
    document.body.innerHTML = `
    <input id="new-account-name">
    <button id="create-button">Create</button>
    `
    boot.boot(null);
    document.getElementById("new-account-name").value = "name";
    document.getElementById("create-button").click();
    expect(boot.NAME).toBe("name");
});
```

However, if I add a `setTimeout()`

```js
setTimeout(()=>{
    expect(boot.NAME).toBe("name");
}, 50);
```

It works and the test passes. Is this how I should be doing this? Or is there an issue with my code?

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestrunallticks  It looks like Jest, like other javascript testing frameworks, has the concept of a "tick" which simulates the passage of time.  I would expect you could use this in some manner to give it enough time for the DOM to have been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never want to explicitly add delays into unit tests because unit tests are designed to run as quickly as possible. If the behaviour explicitly has to do with time (for example, a scheduled event) then you should try to mock out time in your implementation and then simulate it in the test.

In your example, it perhaps would be better to verify that the function (which you may have to mock/spy) which *sets* the name value is called when the click button event is fired. Jest provides this ability to verify functions are called:

```
expect(mockFn).toBeCalledWith('name');
```

That way, you know the event is handled the way you want it to and you've also separated the behaviour (which is persisting the name in some way) from the implementation (changing the value of the boot.Name field)